# How to add only unique values from CSV into ComboBox?

Tags: java, for-loop, duplicates

I want to read a csv File and put words " Jakarta " and " Bandung " in a combobox. Here's the input

```
id,from,
1,Jakarta
2,Jakarta
5,Jakarta
6,Jakarta
10,Bandung
11,Bandung
12,Bandung
```

I managed to get the words and put it in the combobox, but as you can see, the text file itself contains a lot word " Jakarta " and " Bandung " while i want to show both only once in the combobox.

Here's my temporary code, which works for now but inefficient and probably can't be used if the word has more variety

```
public String location;

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {

    String csvFile = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Project Data.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    LineNumberReader reader = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = "-|\\,";

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(csvFile));


        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator

            String[] bookingdata = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            location = bookingdata[1];
            ComboBoxModel model = cmb1.getModel();
            int size = model.getSize();

            cmb1.addItem(location);

            for(int i = 1; i < size; i++){

                if(model.getElementAt(i).equals("from")){
                    cmb1.removeItemAt(i);
                }

                else if(model.getElementAt(i).equals("Bandung")){
                    cmb1.removeItemAt(i);
                }


                for(int j = 2; j < i; j++){
                    if(model.getElementAt(j).equals("Jakarta")){
                        cmb1.removeItemAt(j);
                    }
                }
           }
       }
}
```

Someone else recommended this approach

```
boolean isEquals = false;
for(i = 0; i < a && !isEquals; i++){
   isEquals = location.equals("Jakarta");
   if(isEquals){
      cmb1.addItem("Jakarta");
   }
}
```

This code doesn't work. As the code doesn't stop once it adds a " Jakarta " but it stops after it completed a loop. thus it still creates duplicate within the combobox.

I would like to know if there's any other code i can try. Thank you

Comment: try stepping through this code with a debugger and lets know what the problem really is

Comment: are you reffering to the first code ? it works fine. It just looks inefficient to me. While it works for now because it only has 2 variety " Jakarta " and " Bandung ", i can't imagine if i have to add more variety in the code. I think this is what they call by dirty code ?

Comment: Why would you think hard-coding a single String for comparison would solve this?

Comment: `else if(model.getElementAt(i).equals(location)){`

Comment: it wouldn't. which is why i need to know any other way to solve this

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code the data with duplicates.

Comment: @AndrewThompson will do mate, thanks !

Comment: @ScaryWombat it works like a charm. thanks alot

Comment: @KevinGuswanto got here too late - seems like your problem is solved. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting all the words in a Set first and then add it in the combobox. Set itself will take care of exact one occurrence of each word.

Something like this:

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        // use comma as separator

        String[] bookingdata = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        location = bookingdata[1];
        ComboBoxModel model = cmb1.getModel();
        int size = model.getSize();
        // add all location in set and set will only allow distinct values
        locationSet.add(location);

       }
       // after looping through all location put it in combobox
       for(String location:locationSet)cmb1.addItem(location);
   }
  }
```

As discussed in comments, Sets are meant to keep unique values. Please find the screenshot of JShell below:

[image]

PS: This is just to give an idea and may need some amendment as per requirement.

--EDITED--

As discussed, it seems you are still missing something, I tried and write below piece of code and worked fine

```
package com.digital.core;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
       jframe.setSize(300, 300);
       String data = "id,from,\n" + 
            "1,Jakarta\n" + 
            "2,Jakarta\n" + 
            "5,Jakarta\n" + 
            "6,Jakarta\n" + 
            "10,Bandung\n" + 
            "11,Bandung\n" + 
            "12,Bandung";
       String[] dataArr = data.split("\n");

       Set<String> locationSet = new HashSet<>();
       for(String line:dataArr) {
           locationSet.add(line.split(",")[1]);
       }
       JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
       for(String location:locationSet)
       comboBox.addItem(location);
       jframe.add(comboBox);
       jframe.setVisible(true);


    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, using array or something ? Will really appreciate it if you can show me how to do it, thanks !

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: @AndrewThompson I usually do that and same I did it for this as well. But it seems I missed top few lines. Thanks for editing.

Comment: Is this value `String cvsSplitBy = "-|\\,";` correct?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Lets stick to one question at a time which is how to prevent duplicates in combobox

Comment: @ScaryWombat. Actually the file contain dates month and year and it is seperated by ' - ' , which is why i put it as a seperator .

Comment: @KevinGuswanto Sets are meant to keep unique values. When you are saying its not working, are you saying set still have same value multiple time. If yes, please share the value of your set.

Comment: @KevinGuswanto Where is the output :) Are you about to paste it ?

Comment: sorry, i didn't know how to type properly in the comment section. I put the output in my question. kindly check it out.

Comment: As  you can see it adds another 'from' at the end of the output. i wonder why

Comment: @KevinGuswanto It seems you are still missing something important, I have written the complete code and shared it along with screenshot. If you are still facing issue, please update the code as well in your question.

Comment: I don't know with some people out there, its basic etiquette to share the reason as well for down vote while you are doing it.

Comment: oh ! it finally worked. one final question, thanks mate p.s : i'm not the one who downvoted you

Comment: one final question : if i want to remove the word " from " do i still have to use for if ?

Comment: @KevinGuswanto Yes for that you have to make an if statement or after adding all the elements you can explicitly remove "from" from the set

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `ObservablArrayList` of strings and as you read the CSV file, check if the list already contains that string:

```
    ObservableList<String> locationsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // Add your strings to the array as they're loaded, but check to 
    // make sure the string does not already exist
    if (!locationsList.contains(location)) {
        locationsList.add(location);
    }
```

Then, after reading the whole file and populating the list, just set the `items` in your combobox to that `ObservableArrayList`.

Comment: i have not learned about this approach yet so i'm afraid i can't use this for my project. but thanks for helping anyway ! also i'm not the one who downvoted you, Cheers and good luck

Comment: If there are limitations on what you can and cannot use in your project, perhaps you should specify them in your question? We are here to help, definitely, but that is impossible when you ask a vague question without clear parameters...

Comment: i thought the would revolve around for and if method and or the hashset method. i've no idea ObservablArrayList exists. Still, thanks for your reminder